# generic static method type

Tags: java, generics

I am getting complie time error if type is Integer for static method.

```
public static <T> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T e : anArray)
        if (e > elem)  // compiler error
            ++count;
    return count;
}
```

then I replaced T everywhere with Integer still no problem.

```
public static <Integer> int countGreaterThan(Integer[] anArray, Integer elem) {
        int count = 0;
        for (Integer e : anArray)
            if (e > elem)  // compiler error
                ++count;
        return count;
    }
```

But once I change change Integer to different type Like R compilation error gone.

```
public static <R> int countGreaterThan(Integer[] anArray, Integer elem) {
        int count = 0;
        for (Integer e : anArray)
            if (e > elem)  // no Compilation error
                ++count;
        return count;
    }
```

what is impact of Static method type to this > operator here?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: By naming the generic type `Integer`, you're shadowing `java.lang.Integer`. Why are you using generics?

Comment: That method signature makes no sense

Comment: You need to provide generic type during declaring generic method. This is the convention

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks, I didn't know the proper term for it.

Comment: why compilation error gone when I change type from Integer to R? @Blorgbeard

Comment: If this method signature doesn't make sense then why compilation error gone? @QBrute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case `<Integer>` is not the type `java.lang.Integer` but only the **name of the type argument** and shadows the actual wanted type. At this point, it could as well be `<T>`, `<VAL>` or `<POTATO>`.

In your case this would be equivalent to the following code

```
public static <POTATO> int countGreaterThan(POTATO[] anArray, POTATO elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (POTATO e : anArray)
        if (e > elem)  // compiler error
            ++count;
    return count;
}
```

Since `POTATO` can be any type, the compiler dosen't know how to compare it to another element. The compiler doesn't know how to interpret `e > elem`.

When you change the type argument to something different than `Integer`, the code would become

```
public static <R> int countGreaterThan(Integer[] anArray, Integer elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Integer e : anArray)
        if (e > elem)
            ++count;
    return count;
}
```

Here the type argument doesn't **shadow** the `java.lang.Integer` arguments anymore and the compiler knows how to interpret the comparison.

**Edit:** I posted this answer before your edit, which changed the context of your question.

Answer (score 2):

You are shadowing `Integer`, the correct *generic type* to do this is the rather inscrutable `T extends Comparable<? super T>` like

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, 
            T elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T e : anArray) {
        if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

(and please use braces so flow control is clear). Also, if you're using Java 8+, it could be done with a `Stream` like

```
long count = Stream.of(anArray).filter(x -> x.compareTo(elem) > 0).count();
```

Comment: I have referred same code here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html but When I replaced type T with Integer type till that time it was fine, once I replaced Integer with another type R compilation error gone.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing with `<Integer>` is declaring a new type and calling it `Integer`.  Note that this is NOT the same as `java.lang.Integer`, and is thus not eligible for comparing in this way.

By naming your new type `R`, you are allowing `java.lang.Integer` to be inferred when declaring variables of type `Integer`.